# Web api срабатывает быстрее чем фоновые приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, backgroundworker

Структура моего проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**BackgroundRunnerInput** - Получает сообщение, обрабатывает и отправляет в **BackgroundRunnerOutput**

```
using BackgroundRunnerInput;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**Worker(BackgroundRunnerInput)**

```
namespace BackgroundRunnerInput
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                StatisticOfTest statistic = new StatisticOfTest();
                SolutionService solution = new SolutionService();

                var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = "rabbitmq",
                };

                IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();

                IModel channel2 = connection.CreateModel();

                channel.QueueDeclare("Input", exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, durable: false);
                channel2.QueueDeclare("Output", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved Event");
                    try
                    {
                        var body = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
                        var jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        SolutionAddModel solutionAdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SolutionAddModel>(jsonStr);
                        statistic = solution.Validating(solutionAdd);

                        IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                        props.MessageId = eventArgs.BasicProperties.MessageId;

                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(statistic.ErrorWhileCompiling))
                        {
                            statistic = solution.Create(solutionAdd);

                            jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statistic);
                            body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStr);

                            channel2.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "Output", mandatory: false, props, body: body);
                            Console.WriteLine("OutputSend");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statistic);
                            body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStr);

                            channel2.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "Output", mandatory: false, props, body: body);
                            Console.WriteLine("OutputSend");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {jsonStr}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                };
                channel.BasicConsume("Input", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.(RunnerInput)");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BackgroundRunneroutput** - Получает обработанное сообщение от **BackgroundRunnerInput** и полученные результаты записывает в БД

```
using BackgroundRunnerOutput;
using ContestApi.DataAccess;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddDbContext<ContestApiContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql("Server = postgres; Port = 5432; Database = ContestApi; User Id = postgres; Password = 123;");
        });
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**Worker(BackgroundRunnerOutput)**

```
namespace BackgroundRunnerOutput
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ContestApiContext _context;

        public Worker(ContestApiContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                StatisticOfTest statistic;
                OutputSaveService outputSaveService = new OutputSaveService(_context);

                var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                {
                    HostName = "rabbitmq",
                };
                var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                var channel = connection.CreateModel();

                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "Output", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    Guid id = Guid.Parse(ea.BasicProperties.MessageId);

                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    statistic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatisticOfTest>(message);

                    outputSaveService.Save(statistic, id);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "Output", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.(RunnerOutput)");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContestApi.Web controller** - проверяет есть ли ему нужные записи в бд и возвращает их

```
namespace ContestApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class SolutionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMessageSender _messageSender;
        private readonly ContestApiContext _context;

        public SolutionsController(IMessageSender messageSender, ContestApiContext context)
        {
            _messageSender = messageSender;
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSolution([FromBody] SolutionAddModel solutionAdd)
        {
            StatisticOfTest statistic = new StatisticOfTest();
            var messageId = Guid.NewGuid();
            _messageSender.SendMessage(solutionAdd, messageId);
            if (_context.TestsStatistic.Any(u => u.Id == messageId))
            {            
                var recordInStatistic = _context.TestsStatistic.Where(_context => _context.Id == messageId).FirstOrDefault();
                statistic.Id = messageId;
                statistic.ErrorWhileCompiling = recordInStatistic.ErrorWhileCompiling;

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recordInStatistic.ErrorWhileCompiling))
                {                 
                    var recordsInSeTStatistic = _context.SetsStatistic.Where(_context => _context.Id == messageId).ToList();
                    statistic.SetsStatistic = new List<CurrentSetStatistic>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < recordsInSeTStatistic.Count; i++)
                    {
                        CurrentSetStatistic currentSet = new CurrentSetStatistic();
                        currentSet.IdSet = recordsInSeTStatistic[i].TaskId;
                        currentSet.ErrorWhileRunning = recordsInSeTStatistic[i].ErrorWhileRunning;
                        currentSet.OutputEqualToExpected = recordsInSeTStatistic[i].OutputEqualToExpected;
                        currentSet.Time = recordsInSeTStatistic[i].Time;
                        currentSet.Memory = recordsInSeTStatistic[i].Memory;
                        statistic.SetsStatistic.Add(currentSet);
                    }
                    return Ok(statistic);
                }
                return Ok(statistic);
            }

            return BadRequest("Нету такой записи в БД");
        }

    }
}
```

**Проблема** в том, что контроллер срабатывает быстрее фоновых задач  и естественно не находит нужные ему записи во время проверки  **if (_context.TestsStatistic.Any(u => u.Id == messageId))**

**EDIT**

Вот как web api связан с фоновыми приложениями

```
namespace ContestApi.Domain.RabbitMQ
{
    public class RabbitMQProducerService : IMessageSender
    {
        public void SendMessage<T>(T message, Guid id)
        {
            var messageId = id.ToString();
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "rabbitmq",
            };
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            props.MessageId = messageId;
            channel.QueueDeclare("Input", exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, durable:false);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "Input", props, body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent2 {0}", message);
            
            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.(Domain)");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Это называется гонка потоков (race condition). Никогда **не фиксите это с помощью ожиданий по времени** `Thread.Sleep(2000);` Для реализации взаимодействия потоков есть примитивы синхронизации: вэйтеры и семафоры, а так же шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer. Наиболее подходящая его реализация для вашей асинхронной среды - `System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>`

Comment: Никогда не используйте синхронную паузу `Thread.Sleep` в асинхронных методах, вы положите сервер такими манипуляциями, более того, она просто может не сработать или не дать нужный эффект. Если уж она потребовалась - есть `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: Я сейчас поправлю, это не фикс. Я просто хотел удостовериться что проблема из-за потоков. А так, я полностью с вами согласен)

Comment: а как вообще связаны фоновые потоки и webapi?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` тоже необходимо исключить. Всё что вешает потоки - запрещено в асинхронных методах.

Comment: @Grundy **_messageSender.SendMessage(solutionAdd, messageId);** отправляет полученную модельку(**SolutionAddModel**) в очередь **Input**.  А  BackgroundRunnerInput обрабатывает это сообщение.

Comment: @Vardan_Karapetian, хорошо - отправляет, обрабатывает - а причем тут webapi? Он должен дождаться результата обработки?

Comment: @Grundy именно так. В идеале, он должен дождаться результатов. А результаты из себя представляют записи в БД

Comment: @Grundy сейчас проблема в том, что когда api запрашивает записи их там нет. Так как, backgraundRunnerOutput не успел отработать.

Comment: При таком подходе, как то фоновые потоки вообще не нужны - без них все сразу намного проще становится